# CALL FOR PRIOR ART: GaAs HBTs in RF Amplifiers

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, us7687886

**Information**

**Patent Number: [7,687,886](http://www.google.com/patents/us7687886)**

**App Number: 11/153,078**

**Assignee: MicroLink Devices, Inc.**

**Prior Art Cutoff Date: predating June 14, 2005**

**Summary:** Patent discloses, among other things, an HBT with two collectors with different doping in order to increase on-state breakdown voltage.

**Looking for prior art that discloses using a double collector structure with varying doping levels to achieve the breakdown voltages at the current densities shown in Fig. 5 of the patent (Not the Standard InGaP).**

Answer (score 1):

This might have been anticipated by https://www.google.com/patents/WO2003077284A2 "Heterojunction bipolar transistor having thinned base-collector depletion region" :

> "**ABSTRACT** A heterojunction bipolar transistor includes a substrate
>   (101) that supports an emitter layer (103), a base layer (105) and a
>   collector layer (104). The collector layer is made thin, in
>   combination with a reduction in a base-collector area in order to
>   reduce capacitance, and is made from a wide band gap material that
>   exhibits a high breakdown voltage. Preferably the collector layer is
>   an intrinsic semiconductor material, such as intrinsic InGaP having a
>   thickness of about 90 nm. The collector is thinned to reduce the
>   probability of scattering, enabling electrons to be accelerated to
>   higher kinetic energies due to an electrical field applied to a
>   base-collector depletion region and one present in a base-collector
>   junction."